# Windows server 2008 & Opendns

Tags: networking, dns, windows-server-2008, windows-server

I have a problem, my network have a domain controller, File server, DHCP & DNS server configured on one machine, i would like to filter the internet content using opendns.

but there is some computer on the network should be excluded from this filltring.

Keys:
1. Computers get IP configuration by DHCP.
2. Computers DNS & Alternat is the local server (Could not be changed).
3. Client Computers are mixed (Windows XP SP3 & Windows 7).
4. Server OS windows server 2008 R2 64 bit.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2):

Simply put the OpenDNS servers in the DNS Forwarders tab and configure your DHCP to deliver your Domain Controller IP addres as a DNS Server for your clients.